# .NET application - Status Code: Error 302 Found

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

The .Net application if it is run on the server directly(localhost:5000), I can login without issue. However, if I access the application through IIS - http://hostname and try to login I get error 302 - found. My question is what can cause such an error?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As described at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302), HTTP 302 Found is a redirection response and the new navigation target location should be found in response's `Location` header.

The response in your screenshot redirects to `/Auth/SignIn?ReturnUrl=/Home/Error` page of the same host.

Comment: It should redirect to /Home/Index as it does when I run the app on the server(localhost:5000).

Comment: Is it possible that your Auth/SignIn page is not configured to allow anonymous access (possibly outside of localhost) and redirects indefinitely?

Either way, you will be seeing the HTTP 302 even in valid scenario, this, in itself, is not an error. If you require help diagnosing the issue, you should post detailed IIS configuration and network request log, ideally in textual form.